# Why Future(1) return diffrent result between repl and compiled prog?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

Use future in repl:

```
scala> val a=Future{1}
a: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(<not completed>)

scala> a.value
res0: Option[scala.util.Try[Int]] = Some(Success(1))
```

return Some(Success(1))

Use it in IDEA:

```
object A extends App{
 val a=Future{1}
 println(a.value)
}
```

return None:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\java.exe"...
None
```

Why?There is no something like Thread.Sleep,so in any situation,I think the Future will return immediately,give me Some(Successs(1))

Thanks!

Comment: The REPL is pretty slow, you have to print the previous result, read the next line, parse it, execute it, print it. - Is not rocket science.

Comment: Thanks!so the prog is fast,but I only let the future return a value 1,even it's fast,it can't return 1 immediately?

Comment: No, because creating a future means scheduling the task in a thread pool which is an expensive operation. If you want to return a future already completed use `Future.succesful(1)`

Comment: You can do `Await.result` to see the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Future` is executed asynchronously. It is submitted to the thread pool queue, where one of the available threads picks it up eventually, and executes.

When you are running in repl, somewhere (during IO probably), the current thread looses control, the context switches, and another thread gets a chance to pick up the task from the queue and complete it.

When running it as a program, the `a.value` is executed immediately after `a=Future`, in the same thread, the asynchronous task is still sitting in the queue.